# How to show Changes tab by default in GitLab merge request?

Tags: gitlab

Is it at all possible to let GitLab show the Changes tab when browsing merge requests? It's very annoying to check a lot of merge requests when you have to switch to Changes tab every time.

Thank you

Comment: Nope, not that I've seen.

If you were reviewing my code, I wouldn't want you to skip the MR description I've typed out for you, highlighting the changes I've made and what my goals were. I spent time trying to give you as a reviewer some context when you go look at the diff.

Comment: @ahogen Of course, good point! Thanks for the info. We use on site GitLab at our corp and do those descriptions either personally or in Jira most of the time. Today I had a lot of MRs by the same guy with basically the same changes. Configs for micro services. Was quite hard to keep an overview and I was wondering if I can make it easier for myself.

Comment: Yeah we are locally hosted as well. Just had a set of very similar MRs and my boss/reviewer politely asked me to point out the important bits since the similarities were starting to put him to sleep. So I went ahead and added a "Notes for Reviewers" section to all my MRs, indicating where some files were different or had important bits that should be closely inspected.

Comment: [Agile manifesto](https://agilemanifesto.org/): "Individuals and interactions *over* Process and tools". Chat among yourselves for how the team can help each other. :-)

Comment: That could also be a reasonable solution. I'll have to discuss that. Thanks!